# MIME::Lite package Invalid route address

Tags: perl, email

I'm tying to send email to multiple users using `MIME::Lite` package. I have tried to separate addresses by space, semicolon or coma but nothing worked. I still get the error "Invalid route address".

Comment: Do you send by sendmail or SMTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use the Cc or the To field to list more than one addresses?

This says, Cc field and simple comma: https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite

Comment: Yes the problem was in cc list. I used coma there. The Error message contained only my To list so it confused me and I was digging in wrong  place.

Answer (score 1):

**HOW TO debug MIME::Lite email sending**

I may mean some configuration problems with your MTA/mail server => provide more debug info.

If you send by "sendmail" => append `-v` to default command line options

```
MIME::Lite->send("sendmail", "/usr/lib/sendmail -v -t -oi -oem");
```

OR

```
$msg->send("sendmail", "/usr/lib/sendmail -v -t -oi -oem");
```

If you send by smtp append `Debug=>2` option

```
MIME::Lite->send('smtp','some.host',Debug=>2);
```

OR

```
$msg->sendsend('smtp','some.host',Debug=>2);
```